# Register administrator who creates a backend sales order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm new to magento 2. I need to know the name of the administrator account who created an order for the backend. Is Magento currently registering or is development necessary?

Comment: Magento currently does not provide any feature to track which admin user created the order.

Comment: There are some extensions available which track admin user's activity. You can search for admin logger or some similar term for magento 2.